# Want buttons from vue component used for switching to be fixed in position?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I have vue component used for switching called UserAuthentication between signin and signup components. In this case I have buttons in the vue component for switching for signing and signup. I essentially want these buttons fixed on top of form-box from signin and signup component. Essentially want the button-field from user authentication to be fixed on top of signin.vue and signup.vue

signin.vue and signup.vue exact same just more fields in signup.vue:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class ="form-box">
        <h1 ref="title">Sign In</h1>
 
        <form @submit.prevent="handleSubmit" > 
       

            <div class = "input-group">



                <div class="input-field">
                    <input type = "email" v-model = "email" placeholder = "Email"> 
               
                </div>

                <div class="input-field">
                    <input type = "password"  v-model = "password"  placeholder = "Password"> 
                </div>

                
            </div>
        <div class = "btn-field">
                <button class= "invert" id="signupBtn" @click="signUp = !signUp">Sign In</button>
      
             
                </div>
         


        </form>


    </div>

</div>


</template>

<script>
  export default {
      name: 'signIn',

data(){

return {

email: '',
password: ''
}
},


methods:{
 handleSubmit(){

const data = {
email: this.email,
password: this.password
};
          console.log(data);
      }
  }

  }
</script>


<style>

.container{
    width : 100%;
    height: 100vh;  /*vh stands for viewable height */
    background-color: lightblue; /* can be image too*/
    position : relative;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}


.form-box{
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 450px;  /*set a max width*/
   position: absolute; /*positioned relaitve to its position*/
    top: 30%;
    left: 30%;  /*middled using top and left*/
     transform: translate(-10%,-10%); /*translates box based on cordinates*/
    background : #fff;
     padding: 50px 60px 70px;    /*generate space around box*/
    text-align: center;       /*make sure text is centered*/

}

.form-box h1{
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 60px; /*spaces it out from the fields*/
    color: #2da000;
    position: relative;

}

.form-box h1::after{  /*  */
    content: '';
    width: 30px;
    height: 4px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #3c00a0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -12px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%)
    ;

}

.input-field{   
  background: #eaeaea;
  margin: 15px 0;   /* create space around text between textboxes */
  border-radius: 3px;  /*closes in margin border*/
  display: flex; /*use flexbox for all items */
  align-items: center; /*center all items in the flexbox*/

  max-height:65px;
  transition: max-height 0.5s; /* provides transition */
  overflow:hidden;

}


input{
width: 100%;
background: transparent;
border: 0;
outline: 0;
padding: 18px 15px; /*make padding of input boxes wider*/
}



form p{
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 13px;
}


form p a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #3c00a0;
}


.btn-field{  /* add spaces between flex box buttons */
    width:100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.btn-field button{ /*provides length for flex button*/
    flex-basis:48% ;
    background: #3c00a0;
    color: #ffff;
    height: 40px; /*increase height of button*/
    border-radius: 20px; /*makes border go in more rounder shape*/
    border:0;   /*get rid of border surrounding button*/
    outline:0; 
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background 1s;
}

.input-group{ /*add space between input field and button*/
    
    height: 280px;
}

.invert{
    background: #eaeaea;
    color: rgb(85, 85, 85);
}




</style>
```

UserAuthenticaion.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="user-authentication">
    <div class="auth-container">
      <div class="button-field">
        <button class="b1" @click="showSignIn">Sign-in</button>
        <button class="b2" @click="showSignUp">Sign-up</button>
      </div>
      <!-- Conditional rendering of components -->
      <SignIn v-if="currentComponent === 'sign-in'" class="sign-in"></SignIn>
      <SignUp v-else-if="currentComponent === 'sign-up'" class="sign-up">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="form-box">
            <!-- Content from SignUp.vue -->
            <!-- ... -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </SignUp>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import SignIn from './signIn.vue';
import SignUp from './signUp.vue';

export default {
  name: 'UserAuthentication',
  components: {
    SignIn,
    SignUp,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      currentComponent: 'sign-up',
    };
  },
  methods: {
    showSignIn() {
      this.currentComponent = 'sign-in';
    },
    showSignUp() {
      this.currentComponent = 'sign-up';
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
/* Existing styles for user-authentication */
/* ... */



.auth-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; /* Ensure vertical layout */
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); /* Semi-transparent background */
  z-index: 999; /* Ensure the container is on top */
}

.button-field {
  position: fixed;
  top: 90px; /* Adjust the top position as needed */
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  z-index: 1000;
  width: 200px; /* Set a specific width for the button container */
}

/* Other styles for SignUp component's structure */
.sign-up .container {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 50px; /* Space for the fixed button-field */
}

.sign-up .form-box {
  /* Other styles */
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an updated version of your UserAuthenticaion.vue component

```
<template>
  <div class="user-authentication">
    <div class="auth-container">
      <div class="button-field">
        <button class="b1" @click="showSignIn">Sign-in</button>
        <button class="b2" @click="showSignUp">Sign-up</button>
      </div>
      <div class="form-container">
        <SignIn v-if="currentComponent === 'sign-in'"></SignIn>
        <SignUp v-else-if="currentComponent === 'sign-up'"></SignUp>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import SignIn from './signIn.vue';
import SignUp from './signUp.vue';

export default {
  name: 'UserAuthentication',
  components: {
    SignIn,
    SignUp,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      currentComponent: 'sign-up',
    };
  },
  methods: {
    showSignIn() {
      this.currentComponent = 'sign-in';
    },
    showSignUp() {
      this.currentComponent = 'sign-up';
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.auth-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.button-field {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  z-index: 10;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.form-container {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```